# R shiny matrix or table input

Tags: r, shiny, rhandsontable

I want to create a matrix or table as input for user to interact with in `Shiny`.

### For example:

```
sample name             number of tests
350292                  3
...                     ...
```

I want to automatically generate tabs in the `mainPanel` for user to input data for the different samples.

This is possible with `matrixInput` in the `shinyIncubator` package, but the `matrixInput` function does not support column names.

Is there a better way to do this?

## Update

I tried the `rhandsontable` package.

### Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

DF <- data.frame(name=c(350292, 360765), run=c(3,2))
colnames(DF) <- c("sample name", "number of tests")

ui <- fluidPage(
  headerPanel("test"),
  mainPanel(rHandsontableOutput("sample"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$sample <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL) %>%
     hot_col(c("sample name", "number of tests"), format = "0")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

How can I call values using the `reactive()` and `rhandsontable`?

I want to create tabs based on sample name and test number.

Comment: I think `rhandsontable` would help you here https://jrowen.github.io/rhandsontable/

Comment: I will take a look at it. Thanks, Pork. Unfortunately the user doesn't have a csv/table to import.

Comment: I know, you mentioned that. The package will allow you to create tables on the fly and perform `CRUD` operations.

Comment: I managed to create input table with rhandsontable, but failed to refer to the cell values in the table.